# How to connect Trust Wallet in Javascript?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ether, javascript

I want to use **TrustWallet** for payments in my project for mobile users. I saw the documents related to **TrustWallet** **web3** API but not getting how to use it in javascript. Can anybody help me with the javascript code connecting **TrustWallet** for mobile?

Answer (score 1):

This is done through a web application on TrustWallet browser.

On launch you connect to the web3 service provided by the browser, which uses the same interface than other wallets like MetaMask, Coinbase, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: You can start by looking at this spec https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1102 and MetaMask developer documentation https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs.